# Javascript: pushing CSS style property into array

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs

as part of a larger React-datagrid project, I am defining CSS properties to an array. However there is a lot of repeated CSS properties written out and I just want to group them up via an array

```
let _columns = [];

let commonStyle = {"width":"200","height":"300"};

_columns.push({
   style:commonStyle
});
```

when pushing, just having the property directly written:

```
_columns.push({
   width: 200
});
```

this works, or having a variable (which has a single property value) like:

```
let commonWidth = 200;

_columns.push({
   width: commonWidth 
});
```

this also works, but I can't get the commonStyle array (which has multiple properties/values) to work. Is there something wrong with my style syntax? even when I set the array to have a single property

```
let commonStyle = {"width":"200"};
```

the style still doesn't work... why?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? is the CSS not changing on the page or is it an issue with the commonStyle "array" not updating (which by the way may be fixed by changing `let` to `var`)

Comment: when I refresh the page i expect the properties in commonstyle to take effect but they don't

Comment: i changed let to var also but i have seen no difference

Comment: Well the ones taht work do not have a "style" property in the object... SHouldn;t it just be  `_columns.push(commonStyle)`

Comment: I have a few other properties that don't need to be in commonStyle so it wont just be _columns.push(commonStyle), but I tried that and it didn't work. What I really don't understand is why width:200, works but not style:{width:200},

Comment: So than you need to do a merge of objects... Well style and width are not the same thing.... Your case that works would have to be `_columns.push({
   style: { width: 200 }
});` to be the same thing you tried in code.

Comment: isn't width, height, and all other CSS properties all obtainable via style? i.e. if I were to type in <div class="hi" style="width:200"> ... </div> that should work. So if this is possible, surely my example in original post would work?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between your version (of _columns.push({ style: { width: 200 } });) and mine. Both look the same. If it matters, I have two more properties which is name:'Mkey' and title:'Mkey' these are comma separated so _columns.push({ style: { width: 200 },name:'Mkey',title:'Mkey'});

Answer (score 0):

Your working examples are creating a different object structure than the first example, where your properties are nested in the "style" property name. Also, commonStyle would not be an array, it would be an object with properties.

Try this:

```
let commonStyle = {width: 200, height: 300};
_columns.push(commonStyle);
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's common style shared between multiple components, and it's a large project, I recommend you to create a .css or .less for them.

```
.column{
    width: 200
    height: 300
}
```

And use set property className='column' instead.

Depending on how much common styles you have, embedding style inside the code will make refactoring/restyling much more difficult down the road, and generally a bad design.